# Animate with velocity.js everytime chaning on anchors?

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

My website is only one page, but has different sections using Fullpage.js.
I was wondering if I can activate velocity.js animations everytime I scroll to certain section (anchors), because right now, everything loads at once?

html

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section0">
        <img class="mainlogo" src="img/mainlogo.png" />
        <h1 class="mainheading">company title</h1>
        <p class="subheading">subheading</p>  
    </div>
 <!-- second page -->
    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <div class="slide" id="slide1">
            <div class="intro">
                <img class="icon" src="img/icon.png" />
                <h1 class="firstheading">firstheading</h1>
                <p class="firstsub">firstsub</p>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide2">
        <p class="firstsub-2">Lorem ipsum </p>
            <a href="#"><img class="playstorebutton" src="img/playstorebutton.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['home', 'page1', 'page2', 'contactus'],
    menu: '#menu'

});

setTimeout(function() {
      $(".mainlogo, .mainheading, .subheading,")
      .velocity("transition.slideUpIn" ,{stagger: 250});

        }); 

setTimeout(function() {
      $(".icon, .firstheading, .firstsub,")
      .velocity("transition.slideUpIn" ,{stagger: 250});

        }); 

});
```

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: Everything loads at once? What do you mean with that? And why is that related with velocity.js at all?

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup I have added the code. Sorry about that. What I mean is that I want the animations to load as the user scrolls to the next page, however right now it all loads at once, and therefore people cant see the second page animation

Answer (score 1):

Use the fullpage.js callbacks for it such as [`afterLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterload-anchorlink-index) or [`onLeave`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onleave-index-nextindex-direction).

Something like:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        var loadedSection = $(this);

        //Section 3 loaded?
        if(index == 3){
            $(".icon, .firstheading, .firstsub,")
                .velocity("transition.slideUpIn" ,{stagger: 250});

            }); 
        }

        //Section 4 loaded?
        if(index == 4){
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".mainlogo, .mainheading, .subheading,")
                    .velocity("transition.slideUpIn" ,{stagger: 250});

            }); 
        }


    }
});
```